# Handling AsyncTask duplicating items on refresh

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here's my issue. I have the following code for an AsyncTask :

```
private class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    OkHttpUtil okHttp = new OkHttpUtil();

    private static final int RESULT_FAILURE = 0;
    private static final int RESULT_SUCCESS = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_DATA_ADDED = 2;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ARRAY = "articles";

    private static final String url = "http://x/db/fetch_all.php";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(okHttp.okHttpGet(url));
            result = jsonObject.optInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (result == RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonArticle = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    int id = jsonArticle.optInt(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.ID);
                    String img = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.IMG);
                    String title = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.TITLE);
                    String content = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.CONTENT);
                    mArticleList.add(new Article(id, img, title, content));
                    result = RESULT_DATA_ADDED;
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error parsing JSON Object");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == RESULT_DATA_ADDED) {
            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

}
```

AsyncTasks happen to be pretty new to me. Now the thing is when the user refreshes, I am currently executing `new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute()`.

What this does is adds the same contents into my RecyclerView again. Is there some way I can accomplish these things:

- Detect new data being added without comparing the current fetched item with all the items of the array list to know if the data is stale.
- Prevent the AsyncTask from being run all over again when the screen orientation changes.

Let me mention that I am executing the AsyncTask in `onCreateView()` of my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of clearing your ArticleList by adding

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        mArticleList.clear();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
}
```

or if you want to add things that are not present you could do

```
// add this function to your class
public boolean hasArticleInList(int id)
{
  for(Article a : mArticleList){
     if(a.getId == id){return true;}
  }
  return false;
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(okHttp.okHttpGet(url));
        result = jsonObject.optInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (result == RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonArticle = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                int id = jsonArticle.optInt(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.ID);
                String img = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.IMG);
                String title = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.TITLE);
                String content = jsonArticle.optString(NewsletterHContract.FavoritesColumns.CONTENT);


       //CHANGE THIS BIT TO
                if(!hasArticleInList(id)){mArticleList.add(new Article(id, img, title, content));}
                result = RESULT_DATA_ADDED;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error parsing JSON Object");
    }
    return result;
}
```

to prevent the async task from running on orientation change you have a number of options, either you can check to see if your ArrayList is null so that it will be called on create view (but only the first time) or you can create a boolean called first and initialize it to false;
then after the first sync you can switch it to true and wrap the call to your async class in an if block